replyKeyboardMarkup doesn't work in supergroup
I tried to show keyboard in supergroup ('supergroup' is a group with topics). I use a request like this
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=CHAT_ID&message_thread_id=ID&selective=true&text=test&reply_markup=%7B%22keyboard%22%3A+%5B%5B%22Button%22%5D%5D%7D
where reply_markup contains simple JSON with one button.
It works in bot's private messages, also works in regular groups, but doesn't work in supergroup.
P.S. It work in supergroup on Android, but not on desktop app (I checked Linux and Mac) and web app.
How can I make it working on desktop app and web app?
I tried to add/remove parameters selective and is_persistent, nothing is working.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

I can see there's already a bug ticket on this https://bugs.telegram.org/c/27693

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
